# Python 3.4 Find all file types and copy to directory

Tags: python, file, copy

I am trying to create a backup program to find and copy all txt files from directory and subdirectories to another directory. I am new to python and have tried using glob and shutil modules. I added my paths to variables to make them easier to change.

```
import os
import shutil

src= "C:/"
dest= "F:/newfolder"

src_files = os.listdir(src)
for file in src:
    filename = os.path.join(src, file)
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have: `for file in src:` did you mean `for file in src_files:` ?

Try this:

```
import glob, os, shutil

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.txt"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, dest_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script.
It will copy all text files from src to dest directory (dest is an existing directory)

```
import os, shutil

def copy(src, dest):
    for name in os.listdir(src):
        pathname = os.path.join(src, name)
        if os.path.isfile(pathname):
            if name.endswith('.txt'):
                shutil.copy2(pathname, dest)      
        else:
            copy(pathname, dest)

copy(src, dest)
```

If you need to get the same directory tree, use this:

```
def copy(src, dest):
    for name in os.listdir(src):
        pathname = os.path.join(src, name)
        if os.path.isfile(pathname):        
            if name.endswith('.txt'):
                if not os.path.isdir(dest):
                    os.makedirs(dest)
                shutil.copy2(pathname, dest)      
        else:
            copy(os.path.join(src, name), os.path.join(dest, name))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Im not sure what Im looking at output-wise using your script, I didn't receive any of the errors you have in the print functions if that was to debug my problem.

Comment: @axxic3 If you found it usefull you can vote, ask more ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.4 there is new module [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html) which can iterate over dirs and subdirs.
One possible way to do what you need is create generator which spit out all txt files. Iterate over the generator and use shutil to copy.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

src= "C:/"
dest= "F:/newfolder"

generator = (str(f) for f in Path(src).iterdir() if f.is_file() and f.suffix=='.txt')

for item in generator:
    shutil.copy2(item, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on your inputs guys: just edited the src destination and added "recursive-True" - then it worked perfectly.

```
import glob, os, shutil

src= "E:/Work/**/"
dest= "E:/Private"

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(src, "*string that is searched in name of files*"),recursive=True)
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, dest)
```